# definition of implicitly-declared destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, implicit-declaration

in my header file for my HuffmanTree binary tree class I have the declaration of my destructor:

```
//huffman.h
using namespace std;

#ifndef HuffmanTree_H
#define HuffmanTree_H
class HuffmanTree
{
        public:
        ~HuffmanTree();
};
#endif
```

and in my cpp file I have the implementation of my destructor

```
//huffman.cpp

#include "huffman.h"

using namespace std;

//destructor
HuffmanTree::~HuffmanTree()
{

}
```

note: I have not finished writing the destructor body because I want it to compile

the exact text of the error is:

```
huffman.cpp:8:27: error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘HuffmanTree::~HuffmanTree()’
    HuffmanTree::~HuffmanTree()
                              ^
```

thank you for any help you can give

Comment: Try getting rid of the "void" part.

Comment: That error message sounds like you didn't actually declare `~HuffmanTree();` in the header - are you sure the header file with that declaration is really the one being compiled?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: yes, it is the same file, because I also have my default, explicit, and copy constructors in the same files.

Comment: The revised code is clearly correct. If that's really what you're compiling, then your compiler has a major bug.

Comment: @PeteBecker I just finished removing all code relating to the problem and retesting, the error is still present, and this is all the code

Comment: Do you have some funky pre-compiled header involved? If there's some old cached information, either in a pre-compiled header or somewhere else in a project, you can get impossible errors like this one.

Comment: no, I went through and deleted everything from the files except for what is shown

Comment: @ChristianOlson: Do a clean build or create a new project using just those things.

Comment: @Guvante I won't even pretend to know why, but your suggestion worked

Comment: @ChristianOlson: For some reason your compiler had a definition of `HuffmanTree` that had an implicitly-declared destructor. As Pete Becker mentioned that could be caused by a pre-compiled header or something similar. Compilers aren't supposed to compile old code against new but sometimes they do due to optimizations. A similar example would be setting SVN to checkout with original datetime stamps and checking out a "new" change with an earlier datetime stamp (which would possibly be ignored due to "newer than bin" checks).

Answer (score 0):

In your header add this:

```
class HuffmanTree {

public:
      ~HuffmanTree(void);
```

In your .cpp file:

```
HuffmanTree::~HuffmanTree(void) {
   ;
}
```

Adding 'void' worked for me.